# Text hidden - no anchor points

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, anchor-point

I have some text that came with a file, and I increased the size of text thereby hiding some of the text. I have used the direct selection tool on some text, and chosen the little white box, which I believe is the anchor, and stretched it making the whole word visible. However, this does not work on some text which is curved (see example, mising 'egal'). There is no white box anchor. Adding anchors does not help. Am I doing some thing wrong? I also cannot rotate those same words using the rotate tool, but I can with the Free transform tool (if that helps?). Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

[image: No anchor points]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your text has been written on an existing path with the 'Type on a Path Tool'.

[image]

Any text that doesn't fit on that path will overflow and be hidden—as you can see.

If you want to edit the path, you need to adjust the path the text was written on not the bounding box of the text object. I've highlighted the path and end anchor points here:

[image]

It may be easier to select all the text on the path, copy, draw a new path and paste the text on to that path with the 'Type on a Path Tool'.

---

UPDATE: It seems that if the start or end handles of the text on a path are directly over the anchor points of the path you cannot select the anchor points. To get around this, without anything selected use the direct selection tool and hover over the path, you should then be able to select the path and edit its anchor points.

Comment: Thanks Cai for your quick reply. I have tried your suggestion with both the selection tool and the direct selection tool, but when I hoover other either anchor point the cursor become black with a left or right pointing right arrow. I cannot stretch it. This would be ideal as I have alot ot text like this and it would help not to have to draw new paths. Any thoughts? Thanks again!

Comment: Those arrows show when you select the vertical lines that indicate where the text begins and ends, what you want to select is the path below the text. You should be able to select the anchor point by *clicking* (not dragging) the *anchor point* (not the path) - with the direct selection tool

Comment: Ok, actually I just tested and if the type start/end handles are directly over the ends of the path you can't select the anchor points as you should be able to! ...to get around that, deselect the type - then with nothing selected use the direct selection tool and hover over the path and select *the path*, you should then be able to edit the anchor points.

Comment: @Jim Let me know if that works and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Absolutely Fantastic!!! Thank you soo much!! I got it now thanks to your help. I was cracking up for a while there. Thanks again. Correct and well explained for a novice like me! Thank you!!

Comment: Hover over the path!!

Comment: No problem at all. Glad I could help.